# Sequelize - exclude default child relationship in parent scope

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

I have three Sequelize models in the following relationship:

```
ParentModel -> ChildModel -> ExpensiveRelationshipModel
```

The default scope `ChildModel` includes `ExpensiveRelationshipModel`, and I'm creating a new scope for `ParentModel` that does not need the data from this expensive relationship, so I want to remove it.

Default scope for `ChildModel`:

```
ChildModel.addScope(
  'defaultScope',
  {
    include: [
      { model: db.ExpensiveRelationshipModel, as: 'expensiveRelationship' }
    ]
  }
)
```

I'm writing a new scope for `ParentModel` and I want it to include `ChildModel`, but exclude `ExpensiveRelationshipModel`.  Scope I'm writing for for `ParentModel` is this:

```
ParentModel.addScope(
  'for-recently-viewed',
  {
    include: [
      {
        model: ChildModel,
        as: 'child'
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

This causes the default scope for `ChildModel` to be used, and therefore includes the `ExpensiveRelationshipModel`, which I don't need.

I want to specify in this scope to remove the expensive relationship between `ChildModel` and `ExpensiveRelationshipModel`.  How do I do that in Sequelize 4?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Model.scope('smaller-scope')` then the default scope won't be used.

Comment: In that case I need to ask the question again.  `relatedModel` in this case is a relation of a relation.

Comment: This answer was for an older version of the question.